# PHP - Checking an array for required keys and setting optional key-values

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I’m building a web API which takes an array of data. I want to check this array for certain keys and if a required key doesn’t exist, return false and if an optional key doesn’t exist, set that key-value pair in the array.

The confusion comes from my input array having potentially arrays as values. For example, let’s say I input an array like this:

```
$input_array = array(
    ’name’ => ‘Adam’,
    ‘address’ => array(
        ‘number’ => 12,
        ‘street’ => ‘My Street’
    )
);
```

I have required keys:

```
$required_keys = array(
    ‘name’,
    ‘address’ => array(
        ‘number’,
        ‘street’
    )
);
```

Optional keys:

```
$optional_keys = array(
    ‘address’ = array(
        ‘postcode’ => ‘WA1'
    )
);
```

I’m struggling of a way to test my input array against these two types of test arrays (input and optional).

What should happen is:
1) All of the required keys should be matched.
2) If any optional keys don’t exist, set them to the key-value pair from the optional keys array.

I know of (but am not experienced with) regular expressions. However, I do know that PHP has a function called `http_build_query(mixed $array);` which takes an array and turns it in to a URL query string. My thoughts are maybe I could turn the input array into a URL string then compare it against a regular expression made of my two test arrays (required and optional). Would/could this work?

If anyone has any other ideas I’d love to know.
Thanks

Update: Attached unsuspected output

[image]

Update 2: Attached new output

[image]

Update 3: Current code:

```
static public function static_test_required_keys(Array $required_keys_array, Array $input_array)
{
    $missing = array();

    foreach ($required_keys_array as $key => $value)
    {
        if (empty($input_array[$key]))
        {
            $missing[] = $key;
        }
        else if (isset($input_array[$key]) && is_array($input_array[$key]))
        {
            $missing = array_merge(Inputter::static_test_required_keys($value, $input_array[$key]), $missing);
        }
    }

    return $missing;
}
```

Update 4: New code.

```
tatic public function static_test_required_keys(Array $required_keys_array, Array $input_array)
{
    $missing = array();

    foreach ($required_keys_array as $key => $value)
    {
        if (! isset($input_array[$key]))
        {
            $missing[] = $key;
        }
        else if (isset($input_array[$key]) && is_array($input_array[$key]))
        {
            $missing = array_merge(Inputter::static_test_required_keys($value, $input_array[$key]), $missing);
        }
    }

    return $missing;
}
```

Changed the code from `isempty()` to `isset()`. This page gives the differences between the two. https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Comment: Check the manual http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php and take a look to diff, intersect, and merge functions.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as correct (assuming there was one)

Answer (score 2):

### Required fields

You can use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) for check if any of the required field is missing on the input.

### Optional fields

You can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for set default values for missing fields.

### Code

```
$requiredKeys = [
   'foo',
   'baz',
];

// Take the keys from input
$inputKeys = array_keys($input);

$missingRequiredKeys = array_diff($requiredKeys, $inputKeys)
if (!empty($missingRequiredKeys)) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException(...);
}

// Setup default values for missing optional keys
$defaultValues = [
   'bar' => 'bas',
];

$result = array_merge($defaultValues, $input);
```

### Child arrays

For check required fields or set default values the thing is to repeat the code above in individual functions.

```
function validateInput(array $input) {
   // Above code

   // Validate field subkeys from a parent required field.
   // or optional field with default value.
   validateFoo($input['foo']);

   // Validate field subkeys from a parent optional field without default value.
   if (array_key_exists('optional_input_without_default', $input)) {
       validateAnotherFooInput($input['optional_input_without_default']);
   }
}
```

### Other options

You can play with array intersection, diff and merge in multiple ways checking for those family of functions in the [Array Book](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)

> array_diff_assoc — Computes the difference of arrays with additional index check
>
> array_diff_key — Computes the difference of arrays using keys for comparison
>
> array_diff_uassoc — Computes the difference of arrays with additional index check which is performed by a user supplied callback function
>
> array_diff_ukey — Computes the difference of arrays using a callback function on the keys for comparison
>
> array_diff — Computes the difference of arrays
>
> array_intersect_assoc — Computes the intersection of arrays with additional index check
>
> array_intersect_key — Computes the intersection of arrays using keys for comparison
>
> array_intersect_uassoc — Computes the intersection of arrays with additional index check, compares indexes by a callback function
>
> array_intersect_ukey — Computes the intersection of arrays using a callback function on the keys for comparison
>
> array_intersect — Computes the intersection of arrays
>
> array_udiff_assoc — Computes the difference of arrays with additional index check, compares data by a callback function
>
> array_udiff_uassoc — Computes the difference of arrays with additional index check, compares data and indexes by a callback function
>
> array_udiff — Computes the difference of arrays by using a callback function for data comparison
>
> array_uintersect_assoc — Computes the intersection of arrays with additional index check, compares data by a callback function
>
> array_uintersect_uassoc — Computes the intersection of arrays with additional index check, compares data and indexes by a callback functions
>
> array_uintersect — Computes the intersection of arrays, compares data by a callback function

Comment: Worth noting: short array syntax only works on php >= 5.4, you also have some undefined variables in your answer `$input`, `$inpuKeys` and a fatal error on your if statement.. no closing `)`

Comment: `array_diff`! awesome idea.

Answer (score 1):

New improved version with symmetrical input+required keys...

```
$input_array = array(
    'name' => 'Adam',
    'address' => array(
        'number' => 12,
        'street' => '',
        'phones' => array('home_phone'=>'','fax'=>'555-1212')
    )
);

$required_keys = array(
    'name' => '',
    'address' => array(
        'number' => '',
        'street' => '',
        'phones' => array('home_phone'=>'')
    )
);


function check_required( $input, $required ){
    $missing = array();
    foreach ($required as $k=>$v) {
        if (empty($input[$k])) {
            $missing[] = $k;
        } else if (is_array($v)) {
            $missing = array_merge( check_required( $input[$k], $v ), $missing );
        }
    }
    return $missing;
}

$missing = check_required( $input_array, $required_keys );
if (!empty($missing)) echo 'Please enter your '. implode(', ', $missing);
```

See sandbox here ... http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/23b908b873b053aefb37770f636b63bba2db960b

Comment: My input array has to be multidimensional. The input array comes from JSON POST and can be multidimensional.

Comment: updated answer for infinite depth of multidimensional array checking

Comment: Thanks for your help. This does work, but I’ve just realised that it’s possible for my data (being JSON encoded) to contain an indexed array. For example, `‘addresses’ => array( ‘address’ => array(‘number’ => 13, ’street’ => ‘My Street’), ‘address’ => array(‘number’ => 14, ‘street’ => ‘My Street’))`

Comment: as long as the structure of the $input_array is mirrored by $required_keys (sort of, since keys and values are swapped), it'll work

Comment: Yeah, you’re right. My ‘addressed’ should have been in an indexed array in my required_keys during testing. Thanks a lot for your help. Where optional_keys is concerned, would a simple array_merge work (as @Maks3w suggested)?

Comment: the only prob with his post is that `array_diff` is only 1 dimensional .. but his solution could easily be refactored to work in a recursive function like what i wrote, just as mine could be easily rewritten with a perfectly matching array structure for required keys :)

Comment: good point. Thanks for your help, if I encounter a problem I’ll update these comments. On completion I’ll accept your answer.

Comment: I’ve reached a problem whereby the missing keys shown aren’t as expected. I’ve attached a screenshot with a printout of what is required, input and missing

Comment: i don't see an attachment, but i've updated the answer for symmetrical input+required arrays .. that might help

Comment: Reuploaded the attachment. OK, I’ll take a look

Comment: just realized the `if (is_array())` routine needed an `isset` check ... check the update

Comment: Still no luck I’m afraid. The function returns two keys which are included but doesn’t include the key `date_created` in `occurrences`. See update

Comment: Shouldn’t the array we loop through be the required_keys array?

Comment: Okay, now that works if there isn’t any subarrays. For example, in the screenshot above, all properties in ‘occurrences’ return as missing. We’re getting there slowly...

Comment: can you update the array in the sandbox, and paste the new sandbox url here so I can see the error for myself?

Comment: I’m working on it myself, so it will change. That’s the only reason I’m posting images is because their contents are static. I’ll update my question with my current function. I am testing with the data in image 2 though, both required keys and input data.

Comment: Actually there is a small difference, in my testing it’s as image two except for my input data not including the key-value ‘privacy’.

Comment: Coincidentally I think I’ve just worked it out. See update 4 for changes.

Comment: using `isset()` means that an empty input will be considered valid ... but if it that's the requirement, go4it :)

Comment: That’s fine, not only can the value be 0, (i.e. an integer) but I’m only using the method to test for the existence of the keys. Again, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check if required keys exist
foreach( $required_keys as $req_key => $req_val )
{
    if( !array_key_exists( $req_key, $input_array )
    {
        // if key exists check if it has values set in an array and if 
        // these are also in $input_array
        if( is_array( $req_val ) )
        {
            foreach( $req_val as $inner_req_key )
            {
                if( !isset( $input_array[$req_val][$inner_req_key] )
                {
                    echo "Required key '$req_key' is missing value '$inner_req_key'.";
                }
            }
        }
        echo "Required key '$req_key' is missing.";
    }
}

// Check if optional keys are defined
foreach( $optional_keys as $opt_key => $opt_val )
{
    // Check if key exists, if not copy optional key=>value as whole
    if( !array_key_exists( $opt_key, $input_array )
    {
        $input_array[ $opt_key ] = $opt_val;
    }
    else // key exists
    {
        // if key exists check if it is an array and if optional elements
        // exist, else add them
        if( is_array( $opt_key ) )
        {
            foreach( $opt_key as $inner_opt_key => $inner_opt_val )
            {
                // key is not set, so get from %optional_keys
                if( !isset( $input_array[$opt_key][$inner_opt_key] )
                {
                    $input_array[$opt_key][$inner_opt_key] = $inner_opt_val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Long time no PHP, but maybe this helps.
PS: Not tested and added some interpretation. HTH

Answer (score 0):

So here is my final code for anyone who stumbles upon this/wants to know how I did it. Feel free to submit ideas for improvement.

```
static protected function static_test_required_keys(Array $required_keys_array, Array $input_array, &$error)
{
    //  Loop through each required key and value
    //
    foreach ($required_keys_array as $key => $value)
    {
        //  Check the corresponding value in the input array is not set
        //
        if (! isset($input_array[$key]))
        {
            //  If it isn't set return false with a missing error
            //
            $error = Error::withDomain(INPUTTER_ERROR_DOMAIN,
                                       INPUTTER_ERROR_CODE_KEY_MISSING,
                                       'Missing a required key: ' . $key);

            return false;
        }
        //
        //  Check corresponding value in the input array is set and is an array
        //
        else if (isset($input_array[$key]) && is_array($input_array[$key]))
        {
            //  Recurse the function for sub arrays
            //
            if (! Inputter::static_test_required_keys($value, $input_array[$key], $error))
            {
                //  If we return false from this one, we've found at least one error and don't need to continue
                //
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    //  If we get here then it must be valid
    //
    return true;
}

static protected function static_set_optional_key_values(Array $optional_dictionary, Array &$input_array, &$error)
{
    //  Loop through each optional key/value
    //
    foreach ($optional_dictionary as $key => $value)
    {
        //  Check the key doesn't exist in the input array OR the corresponding value in the input array is not set
        //
        if (! array_key_exists($key, $input_array) || ! isset($input_array[$key]))
        {
            //  Set the new key/value
            //              
            $input_array[$key] = $value;
        }
        //
        //  Check corresponding value in the input array is set and is an array
        //
        else if (isset($input_array[$key]) && is_array($input_array[$key]))
        {
            //  Recurse the function for sub arrays
            //
            Inputter::static_set_optional_key_values($value, $input_array[$key], $error);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you want to run this code.

If it is in the browser or in Javascript.

Since I am in doubt, I've made this:

```
function array_extend() {

    //Detects if we are running in Javascript or PHP
    //In PHP, this will be false because PHP only parses
    //escape sequences in double-quoted strings (except the sequence \')
    $javascript = '\0' == "\0";

    //PHP arrays support 'key=>value' pairs, JS arrays don't.
    $result = $javascript ? new Object() : array();

    $arguments = $javascript? arguments : func_get_args();

    $get_keys = function($elem){
        if('\0' == "\0")//PHP complains if I use the var $javascript
        {
            $object = Object;
            return $object['keys']($elem); //PHP doesn't like the Object.keys syntax
        }
        else
        {
            return array_keys($elem);
        }
    };


    for($j = 0, $length_args = $javascript? $arguments['length']: count($arguments); $j < $length_args; $j++)
    {
        $keys = $get_keys( $arguments[$j] );

        for($i = 0, $length_keys = $javascript? $keys['length']: count($keys); $i < $length_keys; $i++)
        {
            $result[$keys[$i]] = $arguments[$j][$keys[$i]];
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

It runs both in PHP and Javascript.

Currently, I have an opened question on another website, showcasing the function.

You can go on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/polyglot-array-extend-function-for-javascript-and-php to check it.